# React Native - A function does not wait another function return

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn react-native and i created basic react-native project. My problem is a function does not wait another function return value.
As follows i have two functions, `prepareSupplierStockPath()` and `addSupplierStock()`. I called "prepareSupplierStockPath" in "addSupplierStock". I want to "prepareSupplierStockPath" return first, and "addSupplierStock" continue.
I tried `.then()` but i got an error: ".then() is not a function"
Also I tried async/await, `subscribe()` vs. but does not work. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English.

```
export function addSupplierStock(supplier, stock) {
    var pathList = prepareSupplierStockPath(supplier);
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({type: ADD_SUPPLIER_STOCK})
            firebase.database().ref('stock')
                .orderByKey()
                .equalTo(stock)
                .on('value', snapshot => {
                    for(var i; i<pathList.length; i++){
                        firebase.database().ref(pathList[i])
                            .push({stock: snapshot.val()})
                            .then(supplierStock => addSupplierStockSuccess(dispatch, supplierStock))
                            .catch(() => addSupplierStockFail(dispatch));
                    };
                });
    };
}

 export const prepareSupplierStockPath = (supplier) => {
         var pathList = [];
         firebase.database().ref(`market_suppliers`)
             .on('value', snapshot => {
                 for (var key1 in snapshot.val()) {
                     firebase.database().ref(`market_suppliers/${key1}/market`)
                         .on('value', snapshot => {
                             for (var key2 in snapshot.val()) {
                                 firebase.database().ref(`market_suppliers/${key1}/market/${key2}`)
                                     .on('value', snapshot => {
                                         for (var key3 in snapshot.val()) {
                                             firebase.database().ref(`market_suppliers/${key1}/market/${key2}/${key3}/supplier`)
                                                 .orderByKey()
                                                 .equalTo(supplier)
                                                 .on('value', snapshot => {
                                                     for (var key4 in snapshot.val()) {
                                                         debugger;
                                                         pathList.push('market_suppliers/' + key1 + '/market/' + key2 + '/' + key3 + '/supplier/' + key4 + '/stock');
                                                     }
                                                 });
                                         }
                                     });

                             }
                         });
                 }

             });
     return pathList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript callback function in this case.

```
   export function addSupplierStock(supplier, stock) {
      prepareSupplierStockPath(supplier, (pathList, dispatch) => {
         dispatch({type: ADD_SUPPLIER_STOCK})
            firebase.database().ref('stock')
            .orderByKey()
            .equalTo(stock)
            .on('value', snapshot => {
                for(var i; i<pathList.length; i++) {
                    firebase.database().ref(pathList[i])
                        .push({stock: snapshot.val()})
                        .then(supplierStock => addSupplierStockSuccess(dispatch, supplierStock))
                        .catch(() => addSupplierStockFail(dispatch));
                };
            });
         }); 
      };
   }
```

and then in your prepareSupplierStockPath function

```
    export const prepareSupplierStockPath = (supplier, callback) => {
          ...... your code here .....
          return callback(pathList);
    }
```